# How can I move error/validation text to bottom of my input boxes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Currently, I have a screen setup in my react native application where it handles creating new users. The issue I am having is the validation messages or errors messages text I added keeps appearing to the right of the input boxes instead of under the boxes which resulted to input elements getting shifted over. I was looking for something similar to a break element (eg..
) in React Native and didn't seem to find one.

Below is my code so far

````
const SignUpForm = () => {



    return ( <
        SafeAreaView style = {
            styles.container
        } >
        <
        Formik validationSchema = {
            signUpValidationSchema
        }
        initialValues = {
            {
                firstName: '',
                lastName: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                confirmPassword: '',
            }
        }
        onSubmit = {
            values => console.log(values)
        } >



        {
            ({
                handleChange,
                handleBlur,
                handleSubmit,
                values,
                errors,
                isValid
            }) => ( <
                >
                <
                View >
                <
                Text style = {
                    styles.createScrText
                } > Create Your < /Text> <
                Text style = {
                    styles.createScrText
                } > Jobs @Scale Account < /Text> <
                /View> <
                View style = {
                    styles.nameRow
                } >
                <
                TextInput
                // component={CustomInput}
                name = "firstName"
                placeholder = "First Name"
                style = {
                    styles.nameBorderL
                }
                value = {
                    values.firstName
                }
                onChangeText = {
                    handleChange('firstName')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('firstName')
                }
                /> {
                    errors.firstName ?
                        <
                        Text style = {
                            styles.errors
                        } > {
                            errors.firstName
                        } < /Text> : <Text></Text >
                } <
                TextInput
                // component={CustomInput}
                name = "lastName"
                placeholder = "Last Name"
                style = {
                    styles.nameBorderR
                }
                value = {
                    values.lastName
                }
                onChangeText = {
                    handleChange('lastName')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('lastName')
                }
                /> <
                /View> {
                    errors.lastName ?
                        <
                        Text style = {
                            styles.errors
                        } > {
                            errors.lastName
                        } < /Text> : <Text></Text >
                } <
                TextInput
                // component={CustomInput}
                name = "email"
                placeholder = "Email Address"
                keyboardType = "email-address"
                style = {
                    styles.otherFields
                }
                value = {
                    values.email
                }
                onChangeText = {
                    handleChange('email')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('email')
                }
                /> {
                    errors.email ?
                        <
                        Text style = {
                            styles.errors
                        } > {
                            errors.email
                        } < /Text> : <Text></Text >
                } <
                TextInput
                // component={CustomInput}
                name = "passowrd"
                placeholder = "Password"
                secureTextEntry style = {
                    styles.otherFields
                }
                value = {
                    values.password
                }
                onChangeText = {
                    handleChange('password')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('password')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('password')
                }
                /> {
                    errors.password ?
                        <
                        Text style = {
                            styles.errors
                        } > {
                            errors.password
                        } < /Text> : <Text></Text >
                } <
                TextInput
                // component={CustomInput}
                name = "confirmPassword"
                placeholder = "Confirm Password"
                secureTextEntry style = {
                    styles.otherFields
                }
                value = {
                    values.confirmPassword
                }
                onChangeText = {
                    handleChange('confirmPassword')
                }
                onBlur = {
                    handleBlur('confirmPassword')
                }
                /> {
                    errors.confirmPassword ?
                        <
                        Text style = {
                            styles.errors
                        } > {
                            errors.confirmPassword
                        } < /Text> : <Text></Text >
                }

                <
                TouchableOpacity onPress = {
                    handleSubmit
                }
                disabled = {
                    !isValid
                }
                style = {
                    styles.btn
                }
                disabled = {
                    true
                } >
                <
                Text style = {
                    styles.btnText
                } > Sign Up < /Text> <
                /TouchableOpacity> <
                />
            )
        } <
        /Formik> <
        /SafeAreaView>
    )

}


export default SignUpForm```

Please let me know if there is a workaround for this.

Also, expo will not start for some reason, so I might not be able to try suggestions till it's back up. Currently, try setting up for my Android phone though.
````